# third-party 'MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.h' file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, mbprogresshud

I'm new at iOS development, and I want to run this project https://github.com/google/uribeacon/tree/master/ios-uribeacon
that I thought it should work out of the box. 
I've tried to build and run uribeacon-sample, but I can't because I got this error `'MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.h' file not found`
I 've seen that there this this project https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD, but I don't know how to include it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you clone your git, need to get submodules;

> git clone --recursive git://github.com/foo/bar.git

Answer (score 1):

You can also follow the MBProgressHUD instructions and use [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/), It's very simple to use and you can use it to add, not only this one but, multiple open source projects to your own code.